# Django channels : why is channel_layer.gruop_send getting skipped?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-channels

I'm trying to send message though websocket in django-channgels using **channel-layers** but its getting skipped and doesn't even show any exception or error.

I have tried to make it work even in without async and with async but none works.

```py
class stock_consumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):

   channel_layer = get_channel_layer()

   async def websocket_connect(self, event):
      await self.accept()
      await self.channel_layer.group_add("stock_group", self.channel_name)
      u = stock_market(api_key, access_token)    
      u.subscribe(u.get_instrument_by_symbol('NYSE', 'AAPL'))
      u.start_websocket(True)
      def quote_update(message):
         stock_consumer.send_message(self, message)
      u.set_on_quote_update(quote_update)

   async def websocket_receive(self, event):
      print(event)

   async def websocket_disconnect(self, message):
      await self.channel_layer.group_discard('stock_grogup', self.channel_name)
      await self.close()

   def send_message(self, message):
      print("before") //runs

      ***SKIPPED BLOCK START***
      self.channel_layer.group_send("stock_group", {
         "type": "send_message",
         "text": json.dumps(message)    
      })
      ***SKIPPED BLOCK END***

      print("after") //runs
```

Comment: did you try `await self.channel_layer.group_send`?

Comment: @BearBrown I tried but then the entire function `send_message` doesn't run

Answer (score 0):

In your example send_message() is a synchronous method. By default self.channel_layer.group_send is async method. So you should use async_to_sync:

```
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync

# ....

   def send_message(self, message):
      print("before") //runs

      ***SKIPPED BLOCK START***
      async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)("stock_group", {
         "type": "send_message",
         "text": json.dumps(message)    
      })
      ***SKIPPED BLOCK END***

      print("after") //runs
```

More info: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/channel_layers.html#synchronous-functions

Comment: trying this it says `You cannot use AsyncToSync in the same thread as an async event loop`

Comment: Ok, so maybe this is not a good trail. Why are you calling stock_consumer.send_message(self, message) instead of self.send_message(message)? This looks weird. Calling method on class not instance?